# Locked iOS device scanning for BTLE devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Can an iOS device scan for presence of Bluetooth LE devices while locked and then respond to them by opening the app?

Comment: I know you cannot unlock and launch an app.  you could only do notifications to the user when in background mode.  As for the bluetooth portion Im not sure, but WIFI is available so I would think its possible.  Make sure to have the appropriate key in your plist.  (Required background modes)

Comment: If the device is not locked, can the app be opened? Will that be rejected by Apple?  Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you cannot bring your app to the foreground.  if they tap the notification it will automatically bring up your app.  but no, it cannot launch itself

Comment: @owengerig Does this still hold for iOS 7? Is it possible to bring an app to the foreground, when device is in the vicinity of a beacon? I've tried to find the answer but no success as such. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe so @ShobhitPuri but I'm really not sure (haven't tested), but IDK of any changes to the notifications and background task APIs that would have effected this

Answer (score 2):

The scanning can definitely happen in the background.

In order to get the functionality that you're talking about the comment by owen is correct.  I'll expand on it a bit.

What we do is when we recognize a BLE device that we're interested in and would like the app to open we send information to our server, from where we have the option to send a push notification if the user wants.  This could probably also be achieved with a local notification set a few moments in the future.  From there the standard rules apply for push notifications, if they opt to look at it your app can be opened and you can respond to the proximity of the BLE device that initially triggered.  The user always has the option to ignore the notification though.